Problem using cifs-mount in buildroot when application is auto-started from inittab
I'm building a system based on buildroot (2024-02), init (busybox) and Raspberry-pi CM4.
The "home-made" application shall not give any prompt to login, so I auto-start my
application from inittab (just before "getty" is started) :
Last part of inittab:
::sysinit:/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

#Start my "home-made" application
/root/appl

#Put a getty on the serial port
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  console 0 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  tty1 0 vt100 # HDMI console

#Stuff to do for the 3-finger salute
#::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot

#Stuff to do before rebooting
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcK

I can exit the application and return back to inittab to enter getty (login-prompt).
The application is responsible for:

Bringing up the Wlan0-interface (seems to work, I got an IP).
Run "mount -t cifs , "save" and  "umount  when saving file to windows-share.

Problem is that I must exit back to inittab (to login) and restart application to make cifs work.

This fails : boot -> autostart-appl -> save-to-win-share.
This works : boot -> autostart-appl -> exit to login -> login -> start-appl -> save-to-win-share

I have tried to use both "mount.cifs " and "mount -t cifs ", but problem persists.
Any suggestions?

Solution was to launch the application using shell and a script:
::sysinit:/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

#Start my "home-made" application
::sysinit:/bin/sh -c /root/StartAppl.sh

#Put a getty on the serial port
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  console 0 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  tty1 0 vt100 # HDMI console

The StartAppl.sh is a script calling the "appl". Not sure why I have to add a script calling "appl" instead of just calling "appl" directly...
